# Calculating Manhattan Distance in Python in an 8-Puzzle game

Tags: python, search, puzzle, a-star

I am trying to code a simple A* solver in Python for a simple 8-Puzzle game.
I have represented the goal of my game in this way:

```
goal = [[1, 2, 3],
        [8, 0, 4], 
        [7, 6, 5]]
```

My problem is that I don't know how to write a simple Manhattan Distance heuristic for my goal. I know it should be defined as the sum of the distances between a generic state and my goal state. I think I should code something like:

```
def manhattan_distance(state):
    distance = 0
    for x in xrange(3):
        for y in xrange(3):
            value = state[x][y]
            x_value = x
            y_value = y
            x_goal = ...?
            y_goal = ...?
            distance += abs(x_value - x_goal) + abs(y_value - y_goal)
    return distance
```

My problem is that I don't have an explicit representation of the coordinates of the pieces in the goal state, so I don't know how to define 'x_goal' and 'y_goal' for the 'value' piece of the board. I am trying to do it using division and module operations, but it's difficult.

Can you give me some hints to define my 'x_goal' and 'y_goal' variables?

Thank you

Comment: You're right to use divison and modulo operators. Try working out the formula on paper before writing any code.

Comment: I have seen other implementations using division and modulo operations, but they define the goal state in a different way.
My problem is that I can't find anything in common between the elements in the second and third rows of my goal state...

Comment: How about: Relabel the pieces so the goal is 012345678 (easier to think about). Solve (textbook). Restore the original labels.

Comment: I have changed the representation of the goal state to a dictionary of labels with their coordinates. I don't know if there is a better solution, but now it works. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Manhattan distance is the taxi distance in road similar to those in Manhattan. You are right with your formula

```
distance += abs(x_value - x_goal) + abs(y_value - y_goal)
```

where `x_value, y_value` is where you are and `x_goal, y_goal` is where you want to go.

[This implementation using mhd](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/671/fall09/code/python/p8.py) uses this heuristic: the mhd between the point defined by the indices of each of '12346578' in current position and the point defined by the indices of each of '12346578' in `goal`

```
def h(self, node):
    """Heuristic for 8 puzzle: returns sum for each tile of manhattan
    distance between it's position in node's state and goal"""
    sum = 0
    for c in '12345678':
        sum =+ mhd(node.state.index(c), self.goal.index(c))
    return sum
```

Didnt try yet. Maybe link is of some help.

Comment: I know it would work, but a method like this would have a greater complexity than the method I was trying to code...

Answer (score 1):

Most pythonic implementation you can find.

assuming that,

> 0 1 2
>
> 3 4 5
>
> 6 7 8

is the goal state...
AND,

> 1 5 3
>
> 4 2 6
>
> 7 8 9

is the final state.

```
initial_state = [1,5,3,4,2,6,7,8,0]
goal_state = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
def calculateManhattan(initial_state):
    initial_config = initial_state
    manDict = 0
    for i,item in enumerate(initial_config):
        prev_row,prev_col = int(i/ 3) , i % 3
        goal_row,goal_col = int(item /3),item % 3
        manDict += abs(prev_row-goal_row) + abs(prev_col - goal_col)
    return manDict
```

I don't know how else to explain this. It just works. Enjoy ! :D

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same question that you had, and I solved it by writing a different function that takes the representation you have and translates it into the representation you settled on (dictionary of value/coordinate pairs).

```
def make_dict(state):
    coordinate_dict = {}
    for x, row in enumerate(state):
        for y, value in enumerate(row):
            coordinate_dict[value] = (x, y)
    return coordinate_dict
```

That way, you get the best of both worlds. Whenever you want to treat the grid as a grid, you can use the original list-of-lists form, but if all you need is a quick lookup of where the value is for the Manhattan distance function, you can use the new dictionary you've created.

Answer (score 0):

you may be able to use it

```
def manhatan_dist(board,goal_stat):
    #Manhattan priority function. The sum of the Manhattan distances 
    #(sum of the vertical and horizontal distance) from the blocks to their goal positions, 
    #plus the number of moves made so far to get to the search node.
    import math
    b = board
    g = goal_stat

    manh_dist = 0
    for i in range (0,3,1):
        for j in range (0,3,1):
            bij = b[i][j]
            i_b = i
            j_b = j

            i_g, j_g = value_index(g,bij) 

            manh_dist += (math.fabs(i_g - i_b) + math.fabs(j_g - j_b))

    return manh_dist
```

Comment: What is `value_index`?